# UV map is not in the plate

Tags: uv, baking

I want to bake AO for this map but can't do it because the map is not on the plate. Is there a way to fix this?
[image: UV map]

Comment: In the UV editor select the Island and move in along the X axis until it is inside the 0.0 to 1.0 UV space gain. Also don't forget to create a New Image to bake to :)

Answer (score 1):

UV maps are editable in blender. In the UV editor select all (A) (all UV points will become yellow) and drug them with RMB to the desired location, then finish it with LMB. Or use G shortcut to start your "grab and nove".